# How to validate namespace name in CodeDOM?

Tags: c#, namespaces, codedom, validating

I found class name validation method using CodeDOM from SE and I used it:

`System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeGenerator.IsValidLanguageIndependentIdentifier(string value)`

through this link:[Is there a .NET function to validate a class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92841/is-there-a-net-function-to-validate-a-class-name)

But, class names don't allow '.' (OEM period) where namespaces can be something like:
`System.Linq` for example which allows '.'. Before going for options like `Regex` or loops for validating namespace names, I like to know whether there are any methods in .NET for this task.

EDIT:

Actual scenario is, I have a from. User can give a class name and a namespace from textboxes. For that class name and namespace I'll give a generated code. If user entered SomeClass as class name and Some.Namespace for namespace then the generated code will be:

```
namespace Some.Namespace   
{   
  class SomeClass{}   
}
```

For that i need to validate those two names user entering.

Comment: Have you looked at the second method in the `CodeGenerator` class: `ValidateIdentifiers()`?

Comment: Yes @svick, But it's parameter asks for my entire CodeObject. i.e. `ValidateIdentifiers(CodeObject e)`. But I only need to test the string like I test the classname....

Comment: You can always create a temporary object for that: `CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(new CodeNamespace(namespaceName))`.

Comment: Good point. But it's a void method. How can I validate it? There will be no return type. Can you please explain it to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried a different approach and it works for me.

```
public bool IsValidNamespace(string input)  
        {  
            //Split the string from '.' and check each part for validity  
            string[] strArray = input.Split('.');  
            foreach (string item in strArray)  
            {                  
                if (! CodeGenerator.IsValidLanguageIndependentIdentifier(item))  
                    return false;  
            }  
            return true;   
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codegenerator.validateidentifiers.aspx) for that.

If you don't want to check your whole tree, just one namespace name, you can create a temporary object for that:

```
CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(new CodeNamespace(namespaceName));
```

Per the documentation, if the identifier isn't valid, the method will throw `ArgumentException`.

Comment: I also made a custom approach to this. Split the namespace with '.' and check each of it for `IsValidLanguageIndependentIdentifier(string value)`. And it works.